# Именование сущностей

Tags: java, c#, архитектура, именование

Помогите выбрать правильные имена и/или подскажите ресурс, где это уже разжевано.

1. Создан `enum` c разными типами активностей (удаление, создание, апдейт). Как его назвать? `ActivityType` не подходит, так как уже есть сущность с таким именем. `SystemActivityType`?
2. Допустимо/нужно ли добавлять суффикс к классу, если он уже в таком неймспейсе `Constants -> CustomerConstants`? Знаю, что это как бы не ок, но опять же - конфликт неймспесов.
3. У меня есть слой с бизнес логикой, как обозвать его? `Service`, `manager` or `bussinessObject`?

Answer (score 3):

Не вижу никаких проблем в том, чтобы назвать ваш тип `ActivityType`. Просто не помещайте его в namespace `System`. Именно для этого и придуманы namespace'ы — чтобы избежать конфликтов имён.

По той же причине, не нужны суффиксы/префиксы, которые играют роль namespace'а. Для этой роли используйте (... барабанная дробь...) namespace!

По поводу именования слоя бизнес-логики, назовите его бизнес логикой покамест. Если увидите, что он весь получается менеджером — переименуйте. Но не раньше.

Comment: вот именно. Для того в общем-то неймспейсы и существуют, чтобы позволять избегать конфликтов имен

Comment: Так сложилось, что имя уже занято. @DreamChild, существуют-то существуют, но зачем его провоцировать-то.

Comment: @sss: А откуда конфликт? Вы поместили свой тип в namespace System?

Comment: Нет. Мне просто не хочеться писать теперь каждый раз Namespace1.ActivityType и Namespace2.ActivityType.

Comment: @sss: Используйте `using` где надо. (И кстати, в C++ все пишут `std::map<std::string, std::vector<std::string>>`.)

Comment: >но зачем его провоцировать-то

@sss кого провоцировать? Просто пользуйтесь using'ом, и никаких проблем. Даже если вдруг вам понадобится в одном месте использовать оба типа, то для этого существуют алиасы с помощью того же using